# Referencing enclosing namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

This does not compile.

```
namespace n1
{
    enum e1_tag
    {
        FOO1 = 0,
    } e1;

    namespace n2
    {
        enum e2_tag
        {
            BAR1 = 3 + n1::e1::FOO1  // Why doesn't this compile?
        } e2;
    }
}
```

g++ complains that n1::e1 is not a class or namespace.  Eliminating the n1 produces the same error, as does eliminating the e1.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have a typo  `F001` instead of `FOO1` or vice versa

Comment: That should be, n1::F001. e1 is an enum not a struct or class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e1` isn't a class or namespace. It's a variable, of type `e1_tag`.

The enumerators are scoped in the surrounding namespace, so you want `n1::FOO1`. Note that the enumerator contains the letter `O`, not the digit `0`.

Since C++11, you could use a *scoped enumeration*

```
enum class e1 {
    FOO1 = 0,
};
```

to create a scope containing its enumerators. Now `n1::e1::FOO1` is the correct qualified name.

Comment: Thanks!  The typo (now fixed) was hiding the correctness of n1::FOO1.  Guess I need a better font for my editor.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerated types go into the scope of the enclosing namespace. Enumerations don't introduce a new scope. Additionally `e1` is an instance of the enumeration, not a type.